# Is it illegal in Iowa to kiss longer than 5 minutes?

Tags: united-states, law

I recently came across the information that the time of a kiss may be legally limited. Is it true? It's hard to believe those are real applicable laws

> Айова В соответствии с законом поцелуй может длиться не более 5 минут.

Translation:

> **A kiss may not last longer than 5 minutes in Iowa.**

[Source](http://d-awards.ru/458-samye_tupye_zakony_ssha__zakony_shtatov.html)

> Iowa- A kiss may not last longer than 5 minutes.  Also a man with a
>   mustache may never kiss a woman in public.

[Source](http://www.brideaccess.com/You-May-Kiss-the-Blog/entryid/232/25-Kissing-Facts.aspx)

Answer (score 12):

Snopes seems to have a pretty definite "No" in [their article](http://www.snopes.com/iowa-kiss-five-minutes-law/) on the matter.  They state they could not find the law in Iowa's records, and furthermore:

> While this "dumb law" has been shared far and wide on the internet, the majority of these outlets fail to provide any evidence that this law actually exists; when a web site does provide a source link, it is typically directed at the web site Dumblaws.com...several laws (including Iowa's alleged kissing law) are presented without proof. This isn't surprising, as Dumblaws.com writes in its FAQ section that the web site is for "entertainment only" and that the laws appearing on the site have not been properly fact-checked.

They also mention that the earliest reference seems to be a 1998 [website](http://www.jamesfuqua.com/lawyers/jokes/laws.shtml#Iowa) listing "law jokes", again without reference.

Although Snopes deals specifically with the five minute claim, the mustache portion of your question also lacks any proper citation, and typically appears alongside the five minute claim, so it also would appear not to be a rule on the books.

Just to get at the validity of your second source, in item 20 of its list (where you got your question from) I invested the claims of it being illegal to kiss on a train in Wisconsin due to Statue 218.071, and a similar claim that in Indiana, you may not kiss a woman when wearing a beard or mustache, per Section 51.(a) (the only two state laws cited).  Wisconsin's state website has no record of [Statue 218.071](http://docs.legis.wisconsin.gov/search/results?q=218.071&filter=doctype%3Astatutes) existing, nor can I find any reference the cited Indiana law, so I would not say it is a reliable source to begin, rather just aggregating whatever was found on the internet without fact-checking themselves.